# How can I automatically scale up a VM, run a console app and scale down the VM Daily on Azure

Tags: azure, powershell, virtual-machine, azure-runbook

I have this app that I need to execute on a specific Azure VM (GPU heavy) daily. I don't want to pay for the machine running 24/7 and I am looking for a way to automate this. What would be the best approach for this?

I am reading up on Azure Runbooks but I'm not 100% sure if this can be achieved. I was also thinking if scheduling an Azure Devops Pipeline to run and scale up the machine and execute the console app  and then automatic scaling down of a machine if the CPU load is low.

This seems like a typical and basic scenario to which I cannot find an easy solution.

Comment: Have you looked at Azure Batch? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/batch-pool-compute-intensive-sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can start/stop VMs on a schedule in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-solution-vm-management). You could also modify your app to shutdown the server as soon as it exits so the VM is running for least possible time (instead of waiting for the scheduled shutdown).